# Как вычислить индекс элемента многомерного массива в одномерном

Tags: массивы

Значит, имеется четырехмерный массив вот с такой размерностью
a[3][2][2][5]
Как *математически* представить его в виде одномерного массива? Т.е. мне необходим индекс каждого элемента массива, но в одномерном пространстве.

Спасибо!

Comment: Во-первых, какая база - ноль? единица? что-то ещё? Во-вторых - как располагаются элементы, от первых к последним или наоборот?

Comment: При некоторых допущениях и предположениях как-то так: `p4 + 5*p3 + 10*p2 + 20*p1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При нулевой базе и расположению многомерных массивов без пустых мест "по строкам" (последний индекс изменяется чаще всего), как в большинстве языков, индекс для элемента `A[i][j][k][l]` массива размерностью `A[a][b][c][d]` пересчитывается в `B[idx]` так:

```
 idx = l + (d) * k + (d * c) * j + (d * c * b) * i = 
       l + d * (k + c * (j + (b * i))) 
 //уменьшим количество умножений по заветам дядюшки Горнера,
```

При большом количестве подобных операций выгоднее предвычислить  и использовать готовые частичные произведения размерностей, начиная с младшей.

Comment: Спасибо! Сейчас посчитаю на бумажке, отпишусь

Comment: БОЛЬШОЕ СПАСИБО!!!